# Bubble sizes are being rendered too small in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, bubble-chart

Hi I´m working with  BubbleChart on MPAndroidChart .My X values are pretty big and so my bubbles size are very small,in order to see the bubbles is necessary to zoom a lot on the chart.I set big size for the bubbles but they keep small. Thats my code.

BubbleChart bubbleChart=(BubbleChart) findViewById(R.id.bubbleChart);

```
    ArrayList<BubbleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();


    entries.add(new BubbleEntry(323,1f,10f));
    entries.add(new BubbleEntry(981,5f, 10f));
    entries.add(new BubbleEntry(1300,3f ,10f));


    XAxis xAxis = bubbleChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(1440);

    YAxis yAxis = bubbleChart.getAxisLeft();

    yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    yAxis.setAxisMaximum(8);

    YAxis yAxis2=bubbleChart.getAxisRight();
    yAxis2.setAxisMinimum(0);
    yAxis2.setAxisMaximum(8);


    BubbleDataSet bubbleDataSet = new BubbleDataSet(entries, "");
    bubbleDataSet.setColor(Color.RED,180);


    BubbleData data= new BubbleData(bubbleDataSet);
    bubbleChart.setData(data);
```

Screenshot:
[bubblechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgdLL.png)

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem can be solved by pre-processing your data and multiplying by a scalar. So instead of what you have above you can try multiplying the y-values or z-values by a scalar (we've chosen `100f`):

```
public static float SCALAR = 100f;

ArrayList<BubbleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new BubbleEntry(323, 10 * SCALAR, 10 * SCALAR));
entries.add(new BubbleEntry(981, 5 * SCALAR, 10 * SCALAR));
entries.add(new BubbleEntry(1300, 3 * SCALAR, 10 * SCALAR));
```

If you have labels on the y-values or on the y-axis you would then write a custom `IAxisValueFormatter` or `IValueFormatter` to return the original y-value:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return Float.toString(value / SCALAR);
    }
}
```